# Using oracle's to_date in preparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to enter a date in oracle database using to_date in preparedStatement but I am getting errors.

Code Fragments:

```
sql = "select Identifier from metadata where content_cdate >=to_date(?,'dd-mm-yyyy') and content_cdate < to_date(?,'dd-mm-yyyy') and status='published' and content_mdate is null";

ps.setString(1, commonUtil.dateToString(startTime));
```

the dateToString method returns a value like this: 2012-01-01 12:00:00

Error:

```
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use a correct `TO_DATE` format mask to match your input.

In your case most likely: `TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: in the dB the date in stored in dd-mm-yyyy format. Will this change cause any other errors?

Comment: What do you mean is stored in `dd-mm-yyyy` format? As a `VARCHAR2`? If it is one of the date-types then it is being stored in an internal representation and is being displayed to you according to your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: now i am getting an error like this `[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01810: format code appears twice`

Comment: My bad, there was a typo - I put `MM` instead of `MI` for minutes.